# How to define method serializer in Rails netflix fast_jsonapi in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to define a function in Serializer using Rails Netflix fast_jsonapi in Rails as like active model serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the readme of fast_jsonapi

```
class MovieSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attributes :name, :year

  attribute :name_with_year do |object|
    "#{object.name} (#{object.year})"
  end
end
```

Extending on that you could do something like

```
class MovieSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attributes :name, :year

  attribute :name_with_year do |object|
    foo(object)
  end

  def foo(object)
    # do something with object
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's... difficult. This was brought up as an [issue](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/71) a while back, but nothing's come of it yet.

What happens is that the serializers sort of act as singletons, so you're basically forced into using class methods, eg

```
class MovieSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attributes :name, :year

  attribute :name_with_year do |object|
    foo(object)
  end

  def self.foo(object) # will be called
    # do something with object
  end

  def foo(object) # will never be called
    # do something with object
  end
end
```

There's weird stuff around scoping in that gem that makes this necessary.

Comment: This sucks for a couple reasons. My biggest complaint being that memoization is impossible, without hiding stuff on object, (or on params, if you're passing that in) which feels really hacky.